# Performance issue with php/apache/windows. Connection reset

Tags: php, windows, performance, apache

I'm having a rather big problem with a site performance. It's a php site on Apache on Windows Server 2003.

Web site is basically crashing with 'connection was reset' or 'cannot load web page' quite often. httpd process in Windows takes about 100mb on normal traffic, having about 1gb of memory still free

This is first time I host a php site on Windows (WIndows was requirement in this case) and I'm not sure what are my options

Thanks

Apache log is displaying the following (sorry for pasting it like that, couldn't do it as 'code block' from some reason. This surely doesn't look right. Any ideas what could be going on?

> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:43 2011] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal --
>   Restarting the server.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:43 2011] [notice] Child 2072: Exit event signaled.
>   Child process is ending.
>
> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 192.168.67.1 for ServerName
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32)
>   mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.2.17 configured -- resuming normal
>   operations
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 7692
>
> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 192.168.67.1 for ServerName
>
> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 192.168.67.1 for ServerName
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 2072: Released the start
>   mutex
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Child process is
>   running
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Acquired the start
>   mutex.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting 1000 worker
>   threads.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting thread to
>   listen on port 2090.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting thread to
>   listen on port 8011.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting thread to
>   listen on port 8080.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting thread to
>   listen on port 443.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:44 2011] [notice] Child 7692: Starting thread to
>   listen on port 80.
>
> [Tue Nov 08 16:44:45 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with
>   status 0 -- Restarting.
>
> httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
>   domain name, using 192.168.67.1 for ServerName

Windows event viewer is throwing the following

> Error - VsJITDebugger. An unhandled win32 exception occurred in httpd.exe [4416]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

---

Can anyone help with this?

That '[notice] Parent: child process exited with status 0 -- Restarting' is describing the issue here. Tho it describes it in vary vague way. Server is basically restarting on it's own every few minutes. I took the site down with a holding page and the error and restart ddidn't occure. I added an html page and bombed it with combinations of requests using AB. It would always crash at requests close to number of ThreadsPerChild specified in mpm config, which I have set to 1000. Each crash followed with an error

> apr_socket_recv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>     (730054)

That error only displays when benchmarking. Nothing like that appears in apache log. As soon I switch the site back live, it starts to crash every few minutes. The site generates about 100 requests per page and is also using 2-3 ajax calls per page (while loading)

I spent hours searching the web for possible solutions. Found nothing that fits. I'm completely out of options. I'm not even experienced running apache on windows as during 5 years I work in the business I never had to run php sites on Windows. I haven't seen such error on linux neither

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you should have a look:

- Regular Apache logs, located in the logs folder inside Apache installation.
- Windows event viewer, located in Windows control panel

In particular, the second one will log Apache crashes and will possibly reveal additional details.

Comment: just to add, apache is installed on Windows Server 2003 along with IIS 6 which is running dirrent website on different local IP address